# await does not gettng return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I got async function

```
async function getEltern(id){
  var eltern = await getTreeById(id);
  var description = eltern.Descriptions.CategoryDescription;
  description = (description.length > 1) ? description[0].Description: description.Description;
  if (description == 'Test1' || description == 'Test2'){      
    return eltern;
  }
  eltern = await getEltern(eltern.CategoryId);
}
```

however when I call the function

```
var eltern = await getEltern(parentNode.CategoryId)
```

I got variable `eltern` `undefined`. But it returns an object in the function.

Can anyone help what's wrong with my code?

Comment: need some details about `getEltern()` function

Comment: Your function either returns `eltern` before it is assigned (getTreeById may return `undefined`?), or it never returns when the condition of the if statement is false.

Comment: @KhanhLeTran the `getEltern` function is right there, it calls itself recursively.

Comment: sorry my mistake need detail of `getTreeById()` function

Comment: `getEltern()` doesnt return anything in case the if statement isnt correct

Comment: getTreeById return an object. So it should nothing todo with getTreeById.

Comment: it has something to do with recursive? it possible using async await for recursive function?

Comment: @wapt49 you don't return anything from your function after `eltern = await getEltern(eltern.CategoryId);` from your `getEltern` function, so in that case it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a recursive function, you need to return all case you have. With your code, i can see you have 2 case. If the if condition is accepeted it will return 1 value for case 1, and in case 2 (corresponding with else condition) you will call recursive so:

Change to:

```
async function getEltern(id){
  var eltern = await getTreeById(id);
  var description = eltern.Descriptions.CategoryDescription;
  description = (description.length > 1) ? description[0].Description: description.Description;
  if (description == 'Test1' || description == 'Test2'){      
    return eltern;
  }
  return await getEltern(eltern.CategoryId);
}
```